# Welcome User screen firebase integration - unexpected results

Tags: android, firebase, user-interface, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database

I have a key 'newUser' within my firebase database, which can be set to either 'true' or 'false', as shown here: 
[firebase database structure click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8vty.png)

I have referenced to the database within a LoginActivity class, upon clicking a login button the userLogin method is called, within this method I perform the following:

```
 mDatabase.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email)
           .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                       String newUser = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).newUser;

                       if(newUser.equals("true")){
                          Log.d("Yes!", "this is a new user");
                          startnewActivity(singleSnapshot);
                       }else {
                           Log.d("No!", "this is an old user");
                           startnewActivity(singleSnapshot);
                       }
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
```

Note that equalTo(email) ... email is a local variable which grabs the text within the textfield where the user inputs the email. 
the startnewActivity method is defined below, to initialise the activities dependent on whether the user is new or not:

```
 private void startnewActivity(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot) {
    String s = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).newUser;
    if (s.equals("true")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AudiometryNewUser.class);
        singleSnapshot.getRef().child("newUser").setValue("false");
        Log.d("iterated!?", "");
        startActivity(i);
        return;

    }
    else if(s.equals("false")){
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainDashboard.class);
        Log.d("iterated", "");
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

my intention is when the user is a newUser = true, then they will be taken to the welcome screen AudiometryNewUser, and for the newUser value to adopt "false".

The result however is that the user is ALWAYS taken to the dashboard, even if they are a new user. If they were a newUser and logged in, upon clicking the back button the user is navigated to the expected welcome new user activity.
on top of this, several instances of the activity are sometimes launched.

I just wondered if anyone could explain why this was happening, and what am I failing to see?
If clarity is needed please say so, I'll do my best to update the post.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I have, what I think is a working solution now... Having changed the ValueEventListener, for a addListenerForSingleValueEvent, I'm yet to confirm this though, with further testing. If anyone could further elaborate as to why this is the case it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From experimentation and further reading:

The addValueEvent listener is called for every value changed, therefore when setting the singleSnapShot to false this was in affect changing the value, thus the listener was being called again. Instead the correct approach was to user a Listener for a single value event.
When swapped for this method, the solution works as expected.